# Lt-spice switch model

Tags: switches, inductor, ltspice, charging

I have a very simple circuit and want to see the current in the inductor.
But I do not know why switch is behaving like that...[image]

Actually, I supposed to get KA range current. but it gives me very small values.[image]

---

Following I added the same circuit with 5s delay for clafication.
[image]

Comment: Did you graph what your V2 pulse voltage looks like? I'm suspicious of the values you use to define the pulse. It appears that you have specified the rise and fall times to be 0 and I don't think you will really get that from the simulation.

Comment: I believe it's your switch not switching fully....lower Vt or raise the V2 pulse level a fraction and it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

- You have no ground on the controlling side of the switch. I'm surprised the simulation starts.
- You are using a threshold voltage of `1v` for the switch, but a driving voltage of `1V` amplitude. Even if you have negative hysteresis (bravo!), the switch will not conduct the way you need.
- You are using zero rise/fall times, which does **not** mean instant times, that would be a physical impossibility. When they're zero, LTspice uses `10%` of `Ton` for them.

Also, a minor warning: the default inductance, unless it has a coupling associated, has a series resistance of `1mOhm`, which may, or may not be wanted. That's up to you to know.

Here's a reworked version of your circuit, I made several assumptions as I have no idea what is your purpose:

[image: test]